# Hot Chocolate GraphQL DateTime filter not working with 'eq" comparator

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, hotchocolate

I am working on a pure code first implementation of Hot Chocolate (v12.15.2) and .NET 6. I have filtering on all my string and number fields working as expected. However, with the date fields, I can only do greater than or less than. Doing a date equal to date does not return anything.

```
[Authorize]
[UseOffsetPaging(MaxPageSize = 50000, IncludeTotalCount = true)]
[UseFiltering]
[UseSorting]
public IQueryable<ActiveUser> GetActiveUserOffset(
    [Service] IActiveUserService service)
{
    return service.GetActiveUsers();
}
```

And here is the class ActiveUser

```
{
    [Key]
    [Column("user_id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Column("user_name")]
    public string? UserName { get; set; }
    [Column("join_dt")]
    [GraphQLType(typeof(DateTime))]
    public DateTime? JoinDate {get; set;}
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get the date equal to work would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got a type mismatch if you're trying to compare a date and a DateTime:

```cs
public DateTime? JoinDate {get; set;}
```

Even `DateTime`s which are initialised with only a date will contain a time component:

```cs
var myDateTime = new DateTime(2022, 11, 16);

Console.WriteLine(myDateTime.ToString());
// Outputs 16/11/2022 12:00:00 am
```

The issue is if you try to perform an `eq` on a `JoinDate` which is `"2022-11-16 08:00"` with a passed date of `"2022-11-16"`, the date you're passing in is converted to a `DateTime` of `"2022-11-16 00:00"`.

Then you're comparing `"2022-11-16 08:00"` with `"2022-11-16 00:00"`, which are not equal.

Comment: Is there a way to do the eq on a DateTime, since that value is coming from the DB and other systems rely on it, I can't change the type.

Comment: It's actually not that trivial. Imagine your `JoinDate` is in UTC, and you want to filter by date from the client-side. What does that mean? Are you matching in the UTC timezone? Are you matching in the user's timezone?

Comment: The best solution is probably to work out the date you want, then use `lt` and `gte` to filter with an upper and lower bound between 00:00 the next day, and 00:00 the day of the filter.